# Javascript взаимодействие с элементом

Tags: javascript

[image: визуализация]

Как сделать в javascript, чтобы при нажатии на голубой менялся цвет на желтый, а тот голубой, который был до этого, стал жёлтым, а при нажатии на жёлтый он менялся на красным, ну и красный с черным, а черный в свою очередь с голубым.

```
    div = document.querySelector("div")
    
    div.onclick = function (sobitie) {
        if (sobitie.target.classList.contains("div")) {
    
            blue.style.background = yellow.style.background
```

Но меняется только один цвет

Answer (score 2):

Я не уверен что правильно понял вопрос. Вы имеете ввиду что надо менять цвет соседних блоков?

```js
const colors = ['green', 'lightsalmon', 'navy', 'deepskyblue', 'slateblue'];

function wrap(level, string = '') {
  const id = level === 1 ? 'id="inner"' : '';
  return level ? `<div ${id} style="background-color: ${colors[level - 1]};">${wrap(--level, string)}</div>` : string;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', wrap(colors.length));

  document.body.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const next = event.target.parentElement === document.body ? inner : event.target.parentElement;
    [next.style.backgroundColor, event.target.style.backgroundColor] = [event.target.style.backgroundColor, next.style.backgroundColor];
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 2rem;
}
```